# Is it posible to pass a condition that is not Initialized?

Tags: c#, .net

Simply put I was wondering if this is possible?

```
if (Descriptionsearch.Checked)
{
    searchResult = searchResultBuilder(a.Description == textBox.Text))
}
else if (titleSearch.Checked)
{
    searchReuslt = searchResultBuilder(a.title == textBox.Text))
}
```

As you can see I am simply sending a condition of a variable that has not yet been initialized but will be at the time of use.

```
 private List<int> searchResultBuilder(Func<bool> condition)
 {
     foreach (var element in currentPosition.Where(a => condition()))
     {
          searchResults.Add(currentPosition.IndexOf(element));
     }

     return searchResults;
 }
```

I simply wanted to know if there is a way to do this.

since people are asking this is the for loop from my original code

```
 foreach(var element in main.currentPosition.Where(a => (a.key != null && main.msgSigCollection1.msgSig[(int)a.key].Description.IndexOf(searchTextBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) || (a.value != null && main.msgSigCollection2.msgSig[(int)a.value].Description.IndexOf(searchTextBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)))
 {
       searchResults.Add(main.currentPosition.IndexOf(element));
 }
```

where `currentPosition` is a `List<int?,int?>`

Comment: Use predicate builder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: So you know, `a.Description == textBox.Text` is a boolean value, not a `Func<Boolean>`

Comment: Why don't you just test it rather than post it to SO.  And you are not returning a list<int>.

Comment: Could you post the trying you're trying to solve, rather than your method of getting there?

Comment: I have it does not work, this I an example of the code I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell based on your question, but I think what you want is to be passing lambdas, which is not what you're doing currently.

Something like this seems closer to what you want:

```
if(Descriptionsearch.checked == true)
    searchReuslt = searchResultBuilder(a => a.Description == textBox.Text))
else if(titleSearch.checked == true)
    searchReuslt = searchResultBuilder(a => a.title == textBox.Text))

private List<int> searchResultBuilder<T>(Func<T, bool> condition){
     var searchResults = new List<int>();
     foreach (var element in currentPosition.Where(condition))
     {
          searchResults.Add(currentPosition.IndexOf(element));
     }
     return searchResults;
 }
```

In truth though, your question should state what you're trying to accomplish, not just how you're attempting to get there. There probably is a much easier way to accomplish everything you're trying to do here with LINQ.

Comment: I am making a Find dialog with many different options such as match case and other.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a lambda syntax to achieve what you want.

Ex: `(input parameters) => expression`

```
if(Descriptionsearch.checked == true)
    searchReuslt = searchResultBuilder(a => a.Description == textBox.Text))
else if(titleSearch.checked == true)
    searchReuslt = searchResultBuilder(a => a.title == textBox.Text))
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: This won't work as you've written it. `Where` expects a `Func<T, bool>` not a `Func<bool>`.